# Angular reactive forms - get maxlength?

Tags: angular

I'm using angular reactive forms for a component library, and there are some requirements for the project that would be made much easier if I could just get the associated maxlength validator (if one exists) inside a form control (it's supposed to show how many characters are left when the EU is typing)

Specifically, I want to do it from *within the component*, based on whatever maxlength validator was used, as this is a generic branded component library for use within my company.

As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is to pass in the maxlength separately from the validators - but figured I'd ask The Internets to see if there's a cooler way.

I've implemented (and modernized for angular 12) the ControlValueAccessorConnector solve from https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-a0ed4ad0fafd - so I have access to all those properties.

Any help - or a validation that what I'm looking for is not gonna happen - would be appreciated!

Comment: See the usage comments [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#maxLength). The `maxlength` error object has `requiredLength` and `actualLength` properties that may help you.

Comment: Doesn't that only get returned on error though?  The design has the maximum length and the characters entered, regardless of if it exceeds or not - kinda like the "characters left" below the comment form

Comment: Would you mind building a minimum reproducible version of what you are asking, in here: https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy ? then you can add a link to in into your question. it would make it easier for you to get help.

Comment: @CountSpatula Can you please add a bit of the code in the question? How you are creating the form & how you are passing the control to your library component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thre're not a "relation" between a FormControl and a input (a FormControl is independient of the input), so you can not access to the htmlElement input if you not use one around-work: a directive

If the selector of one directive is `'[formControl], [formControlName]'` it is applied to all the inputs with formControl and FormControlName.

We inject in constructor the NgControl and the ElementRef

```
constructor(private control:NgControl,private el:ElementRef) { }
```

So we can access to the function validator of the control using `this.control.control.validator`. See that in this way we access to the "function". And as all the function we can feed with a FormControl and get the result. In this case we are feeding with a FormControl very large

The directive can be some like

```
@Directive({
  selector: ''[formControl], [formControlName]''
})
export class AddMaxLengthDirective implements OnInit{

  constructor(private control:NgControl,private el:ElementRef) { }
  ngOnInit()
  {
    //we need check if the control has "any" validator
    const err=this.control.control.validator?
        this.control.control.validator(
            new FormControl(".".repeat(10000000))):null

    if (err && err.maxlength && err.maxlength.requiredLength)
         this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute(
                 'maxlength',err.maxlength.requiredLength)

  }

}
```

When we has the attribute maxlength in our input, we can write in .html some like

```
<input #input [formControl]="control">
<span *ngIf="input.getAttribute('maxlength') as max">
  left {{ +max - input.value.length }} characters
</span>
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cm1jd7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadd-max-length.directive.ts). If you use F12, you can inspect the DOM and see how is added the maxlength attribute

NOTE: don't forget add the directive in your module!

**Update** We can also improve the directive to add automatically the message. For this we can use the Netanel Basal's idea in his article [Makes your angular form's error appear magically](https://netbasal.com/make-your-angular-forms-error-messages-magically-appear-1e32350b7fa5)

We create a counterComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-help',
  template: `<p class="count-help">{{_text}}</p>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['./count.component.css']
})
export class CountComponent {
  _text;

  @Input() set text(value) {
    if (value !== this._text) {
      this._text = value;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  };
 constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

}
```

And our directive makes use of the Netanel Basal's idea

```
export class AddMaxLengthDirective implements OnInit {
  ref: ComponentRef<CountComponent>
  max:number=0;
  subscription:any;
  constructor(
    private control: NgControl,
    private el: ElementRef,
    private vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    const err = this.control.control.validator
      ? this.control.control.validator(new FormControl('.'.repeat(10000000)))
      : null;
      if (err && err.maxlength && err.maxlength.requiredLength) {

      this.max=err.maxlength.requiredLength;
      this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute(
        'maxlength',
        this.max
      );
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CountComponent);
      this.ref = this.vcr.createComponent(factory);
      this.subscription=this.control.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(this.control.value))
      .subscribe(res=>{
        this.ref.instance.text='left '+(this.max-res.length)+' characters'
      })
    }
  }
  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
}
```

See the [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aaddfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadd-max-length.directive.ts)

Comment: I update the answer because we need check if the FormControl has any validator

Comment: Thanks - I think that'll get me there, you definitely understood what I was trying to accomplish!!