# Angular 12 - Character counter - Binding property input initialization of component in a directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to build a "Character Counter" Angular directive for a custom component  which I can't use ngModel to bind the value. (`my-component` shown below is really complex so, I ask to trust me and long term goal is to use the same directive thru different components). **I have to intercept when the initialText input property is set**, and of course when changedText is triggered

```
<my-component
      characterCount
      [initialText]="value"
      (changedText)="valueChange.emit($event)">
</my-component>

  @Input() initialText;
  @Output() changedText: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

I have already figured out how to intercept `changedText`

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[characterCount]",
})
...
  @HostListener("changedText", ["$event"])
  changeText(changedText){
    this.setCharacterCount(changedText);
  }
```

but I don't know how to intercept when the `initialText` property is set.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70900931/angular-reactive-forms-get-maxlength/70908177#70908177) someone ask about add a maxlength to a formControl

The same idea

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-help',
  template: `<p class="count-help">{{_text}}</p>`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['./count.component.css']
})
export class CountComponent {
  _text;

  @Input() set text(value) {
    if (value !== this._text) {
      this._text = value;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  };
 constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

}
```

And the directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[characterCount]',
})
export class CountLengthDirective implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  ref: ComponentRef<CountComponent>;
  subscription: any;
  constructor(
    @Self() private control: NgControl,
    private el: ElementRef,
    private vcr: ViewContainerRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(CountComponent);
      this.ref = this.vcr.createComponent(factory);
      this.subscription = this.control.valueChanges
        .pipe(startWith(this.control.value))
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.ref.instance.text =this.control.value.length+' characters'
        });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r4awpf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcount-length.directive.ts)